# How to call a function after performing a segue in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, function, segue

Hello I want to know what is the best way to call a `func` after performing a `segue` on swift. I want to click on a button and perform a `segue` and start my `viewDidLoad()` with a new `func`.

```
//FIRST VIEW CONTROLLER

import UIKit

class CelebritiesViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    questionsLevel1()
    pickingRandomQuestion()
    hide()
    finishGame.hidden = true
    nextLevel.hidden = true

    if isButtonClick == true {
        questionsLevel2()
    }

}
}
//SECOND VIEW CONTROLLER


import UIKit

class Level2Section: UIViewController {

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "level2" {
        if let destinationLevel2 = segue.destinationViewController as? CelebritiesViewController {
            destinationLevel2.isButtonClick = true
        }
    }
}
}
```

PS: After finish first section of questions user can choose to finish the game or go to next level, next level is a new view controller so we performing this segue in a second view controller not in the same one.

Comment: so you want to call second function after that particular button only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ViewController1:**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueIdentifierHere" {
        if let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2 {
            destVC.isButtonClick = true
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController2:**

*Define a Bool:*

```
var isButtonClick:Bool!
```

*ViewDidLoad():*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    questionsLevel1()//This is my first section of questions
    pickingRandomQuestion()//My function to make a random number of questions

    if isButtonClick == true {
        isButtonClick = !isButtonClick
        callSecondFunction()
    }

}
```

Comment: I did everything but still calling `questionLevel1` and trowing one question from `questionLevel1` and one from my `questionLevel2`!! I don't know if Im doing something wrong

Comment: you do not want to call `questionLevel1()` and `pickingRandomQ..()` on segue?

Comment: yes I want to call `questionLevel1()` on `viewDidLoad` but just only one time, when the game starts after the user select the next level just call `questionLevel2()`! you know what Im trying to do?

Comment: are you re-using same view controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123628/discussion-between-mr-ub-and-roberto-viramontes).

Comment: Does it helped?

Comment: it work but the answers are not showing in the view controller